# How to open Excel 2003 using .NET 3.5?

Tags: .net-3.5, excel-2003

I'd like to open EXCEL 2003 from a .NET 3.5 application and manipulate each cell in the Excel sheet.  Any one does that?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you mean by "manipulate".  If you want to transfer data to the cells, this Microsoft article should get you going:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306023

Comment: That is not .Net and will barely help him.

Comment: Sorry.  You are correct.  I updated the link to refer to an ADO.NET article.

Comment: This answer should be SO automated response for any question that has the keywords Excel and Cell.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways to do this.

You can use COM Interop to control Excel and open and manipulate a spreadsheet.  This should be avoided where possible.

You can use OleDb to open an Excel spreadsheet as an SQL database.  This will be fast and efficient, but might not be powerful enough for you.  **[Example](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/bee7b2d4-b0d8-470a-9aa0-6bf40d8f588d)**

You can buy a third-party Excel component, from vendors like Aspose or SyncFusion.  This will cost money.